# Amcharts Pie chart - Truncate long labels with small percentages but show them properly in tooltip

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts, amcharts4

I am working with amcharts 4 pie charts. I want to truncate labels which are long and share small percentage so they don't go outside pie chart boundaries as shown in attached image https://ibb.co/0mJnrgy

As per the amcharts documentation  (https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/dealing-with-piechart-labels-that-dont-fit/) I tried  `truncate=false` but unfortunately that didn't work, Not sure why.

So I tried to achieve it using adapters. Below is what I tried so far.
This is working but label as well as tooltip both getting truncated. I have gone through lot of documentation but haven't found any proper solution.

Any clue or help is very appreciated.

Demo & progress : https://codepen.io/amitpatil/pen/bGYEdXK?editors=0110

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Managed to find the solution after wasting so many hours.

```
  series.slices.template.adapter.add('tooltipText', (tooltipText, target) => {
    const {
      dataItem: {
        values: {value : {percent}},
        component: { dataFields : {category} }
      }
    } = target;
    return `${target.dataItem._dataContext[category]} : ${percent}%`;
  });
```

Here is the complete demo https://codepen.io/amitpatil/pen/jOaqJOz?editors=0010